# Confusion on getElementsByTagName with soap response

Tags: java, xml, getelementsbytagname

Hi I am consuming a web service.  I get xml that begins (of course) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
```

which I put in a variable called responseXML

I convert it to a document with

```
Document resultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXML)));
```

no worries so far:

next I have this code:

```
Element rootElement = resultDocument.getDocumentElement();
```

which reuturns the soapenv:Envelope element as expected.

then I try:

```
NodeList bodyList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Body");
```

this returns an empty NodeList, even though:

```
rootElement.getFirstChild().getNodeName() returns soapenv:Body
```

also:
    rootElement.getFirstChild().getNodeType() returns 1 (element)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `rootElement.getElementsByTagName("Body")`, this is because the Document recognizes the schema name `soapenv`

Comment: Try resultDocument.getElementsbyTagName("soapenv:Body")

Comment: The way you described this, it *should* work, that is, `bodyList.getLength()` *should* be `1`. (I didn't test it but I can't see from what you post it how you could be getting a different value.) There may be some other cause. It would help to know when you are reading this value. Could you post your full code?